# Can't Select date range when months go from 'single' digit to 'double digit when querying SQLite Database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am working on a new WPF project where a user can fill out fields to submit to an SQLite database in C#. Submission and retrieval of information from the database works fine until the user selects a date range that crosses from September to October and from December to January. Then no records are returned even if there are records in that date range. You can have a date range from January to September and October to December, but if you cross from single digit months to double digit months then nothing is returned.

I know SQLite apparently doesn't have "date" as a datatype but when I created my database it made it with "DATE" and didn't get any problems. I have also made it with "TEXT" but both have the same date range problem. I am using "System.Data.SQLite" to create and query the database.

my command string for querying consists of:

`string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE DATE >= '" + dateFrom + "' AND DATE <= '" + dateTo + "'";`
dateFrom and dateTo strings formatted as "9/30/2019" and "10/31/2019"
I have tried formatting both dates as "MM/DD/YYYY" but that doesn't help.
I have tried using "BETWEEN" and it doesn't help.
I have tried using the "date" function in SQLite and it doesn't work in C# I guess.

My connection string is:

`"data source=" + database + ";datetimeformat=CurrentCulture"`

I cannot paste the whole code because it is related to my job.

UPDATE:
Thank you for the responses and answers. I got everything to work after changing my date format to fit SQLite. Another thing I missed was when getting the date text from my date picker widget in WPF it was obviously giving me single digits for dates like "9/1/2019" which caused and after I added in logic to add 0's to my SQLite converter function the date ranges can successfully be found.

Comment: Beware of SQL Injection attacks. Also, if you're using text to represent dates in Sqlite, you should be using the [documented format](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) which is `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"` (BTW, it's documented as ISO8601 but it's not. the ISO8601 format does not use space as a separator between the date and time portions, but the letter `T`.)

Comment: Use one of the formats understood by sqlite date and time functions, since they can be meaningfully compared and ordered. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: (Personally, I use Unix timestamps instead of strings since an integer is more compact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know SQLite apparently doesn't have "date" as a datatype but when I created my database it made it with "DATE" and didn't get any problems.

Unlike other databases the column type in SQLite is very flexible and has little bearing on the how the underlying data is stored. In short you can use virtually any type or even no type at all.

The column type ends of with a derived column type (type affinity) based upon a set of rules DATE, MY_DATE, A_DATE even RUMPLESTILTSKIN all end up with the catch-all NUMERIC type affinity.

However, type affinity doesn't play that much of a role. In fact in SQLite you can store any type of data in any column (bar 1 exception, that being the rowid or an alias of the rowid column).

- See [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

However, SQLite does have very powerful [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

- > I have tried using the "date" function in SQLite and it doesn't work in C# I guess.
- They are part of SQLite, they work with SQLite irrespective of the language used to invoke SQLite commands.

  - They don't work because of the format. Consider this snippet :-
  - `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS anothertable (DATE);
    INSERT INTO anothertable VALUES ('09/30/2019'),('2019-09-30'),('31/10/2019'),('2019-10-31');
    SELECT *, date(DATE), datetime(DATE) FROM anothertable;`
  - The result being :-
  - [image]

The Date and Time functions being useful if the date/time is stored in a recognised format as per :-

> #### Time Strings
>
> ```
> A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> YYYY-MM-DD
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> HH:MM
> HH:MM:SS
> HH:MM:SS.SSS
> now
> DDDDDDDDDD
> ```

**As such it is likely best to utilise such formats.**

Assuming you use 2019-09-30 (instead of 9/30/2019) then such dates are directly comparable that is `WHERE DATE BEWTEEN 2019-09-30 AND 2019-10-31` would work as would

`string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE DATE >= '" + dateFrom + "' AND DATE <= '" + dateTo + "'";` (assuming that dateFrom and dateTo were so formatted).

The Reason why 9/30/2019 is greater than 10/31/2019 is that the comparison is textual so the character **9** is greater than the character *1* (comparison is over). Likewise 2/1/1700 is greater then 11/12/2099.

The alternative is to include some relatively complex manipulation e.g. :-

```
-- An example that would handle dd/mm/yyyy where dd and mm could be either 1 or 2 characters
WITH 

    -- First CTE gets the day and the rest of the date
    ctedaypart AS (
        SELECT 
            rowid AS daypartid, 
            substr(DATE,1,instr(DATE,'/')-1) AS day_part, 
            substr(DATE,instr(DATE,'/')+1) AS rest_after_day 
        FROM mytable
    ),

    -- Second CTE gets the month and the rest of the date
    ctemonthpart AS (
        SELECT 
            daypartid AS monthpartid,
            substr(rest_after_day,1,instr(rest_after_day,'/')-1) AS month_part, 
            substr(rest_after_day,instr(rest_after_day,'/')+1) AS year 
        FROM ctedaypart
    ),

    -- Third CTE expands the day and month the have a leading 0 id less than 10 and joins the parts to form YYYY-MM-DD 
    expandedparts AS (
        SELECT
            *,
            mytable.rowid AS expandedpartsid,
          year||'-'||
            CASE WHEN length(month_part) = 1 THEN '0'||month_part ELSE month_part END ||'-'||
            CASE WHEN length(day_part) = 1 THEN '0'||day_part ELSE day_part END AS date_in_sqlite_format
        FROM mytable JOIN ctedaypart ON mytable.rowid = daypartid  JOIN ctemonthpart ON daypartid = monthpartid)

SELECT mytable.* FROM mytable JOIN expandedparts ON mytable.rowid = expandedpartsid WHERE (date_in_sqlite_format) BETWEEN ('2019-01-01') AND ('2019-03-31');
```